# The reset of one array affecting a different array

Tags: arrays, p5.js, 2d-games

I'm not entirely sure whats going on here. When you shoot all three bullets and the last one leaves the screen the "asteroids" array also resets.

EDIT:
Is it because the bullets array ends up being spliced to an undefined when they all leave the screen? Or will it return the base empty array? Even then, it doesn't explain why the asteroids array is voided as well. I also found that the asteroids don't even start falling unless I've shot at least once.

[Code on p5web editor](https://editor.p5js.org/CaptainHawaii/sketches/GayEVG_UG)

What is it causing this to happen? This is the first time I've coded something this large, code amount wise, but I made sure to use obvious variable names for the most part.

Comment: Please put  your code in the question itself. External links can change over time, rendering the question irrelevant for future visitors. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Its way too much code and I thought that putting excess code in your posts was a bad thing...

Comment: Yeah, you're right, so the idea is to create something called a [mcve] which takes a bit of effort to create. But in the process of reducing the code, you might discover the problem yourself. I know that sounds lame, but it's sort of the standard for reporting bugs and asking for help with code. I'm taking a look at your code and I'm not sure I totally understand the problem, but I'll let you know if I see anything.

Comment: I feel you, alright that in itself is probably the kick in the pants I needed lol

Comment: Moved to main thread

Comment: This is an old and resolved question, but it's still worth moving the relevant code into the question itself for posterity--it might help someone else down the line. I can't do it for OP because of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348698/edits-that-add-ops-code-from-3rd-party-site-where-the-license-is-unavailable) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344484/pasting-fiddle-snippet-into-original-question-as-an-edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `asteroids` class:

```
check(bullets) {
    for (let i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
        if (dist(bullets[i].x, bullets[i].y, this.pos.x, this.pos.y) < this.r) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

If there are no bullets to check, this function returns `undefined` implicitly, which is taken as falsey by the calling code, which promptly destroys the asteroid as if it had collided with a bullet.

Also, if there are bullets to check and the first one happens to not collide, the loop breaks prematurely with `else { return true; }`, possibly missing collisions.

Change it to:

```
check(bullets) {
    for (let i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
        if (dist(bullets[i].x, bullets[i].y, this.pos.x, this.pos.y) < this.r) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true; // no collisions (or bullets.length === 0)
}
```

Having said this, the function name `check` is pretty unclear. I'd rename it as `collidesWith(bullets)` and invert the boolean--it makes more sense to say "true, yes, we did collide with a bullet" than "false, yes, we did collide with a bullet". We can also make use of the `for ... of` loop construct. This gives us:

```
collidesWith(bullets) {
    for (const bullet of bullets) {
        if (dist(bullet.x, bullet.y, this.pos.x, this.pos.y) < this.r) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

You could shorten this further to:

```
collidesWith(bullets) {
  return bullets.some(e => dist(e.x, e.y, this.pos.x, this.pos.y) < this.r);
}
```

Similarly, I'd change `bullet.check()` to `bullet.outOfBounds()` or similar.

Another tip: iterate in reverse over any arrays you plan to slice the current element from:

```
for (let j = asteroids.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
   // code that could call `.splice(j, 1)`
}
```

Otherwise, after splicing, your loop will skip an element and you might miss a collision.

A minor design point, but `player.controls()` seems strange--why should the player be responsible for listening for keypresses? I'd listen in the `keyPressed()` function and send the changes to update the player position from there. I'd also break up `draw` into smaller functions. But these are minor design decisions so the above is enough to get you rolling.

Here's a first revision for the `draw` function, adjusted to match the modified booleans:

```
function draw() {
  background(0);
  scene();

  if (tick <= 0) {
    if (asteroids.length < asteroidsLimit) {
      asteroids.push(new Asteroid());
    }

    tick = 60;
  }

  for (let i = asteroids.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (asteroids[i].collidesWith(bullets)) {
      asteroids.splice(i, 1);
    } 
    else {
      asteroids[i].update();
      asteroids[i].display();
    }
  }

  for (let i = bullets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (bullets[i].outOfBounds()) {
      bullets.splice(i, 1);
    } 
    else {
      bullets[i].update();
      bullets[i].display();
    }
  }

  image(ship, player.x, player.y);
  player.controls();
  tick--;
}
```